# Botulisum and Food safety

Tags: food-safety

Should i worry? We just had a vinagret made with olive oil, crushed garlic, white wine vinager, dijon and chives. It was on the counter in air tight container for 6 hours and then stored in fridge for 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

I would chunk it, better to waste it than risk illness. Fresh garlic and olive oil left at room temperature for a significant amount of time (not like the 10 minutes it might sit during prep for addition to soup, pasta, etc.) makes a prime breeding ground for botulism.

Potentially dangerous things like this shouldn't sit out longer than 2 hours at room temperature. Three days in the fridge would be fine if it were safe when it went in, but in this case it wasn't.

For further information:

[Brief write up on harvesting and storing garlic from UC Davis](http://nchfp.uga.edu/publications/uc_davis/uc_davis_garlic.pdf)

[FDA sheet on the temperature danger zone and two hour rule](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/danger-zone-40-f-140-f/CT_Index)

[Flavored vinegars and oils, article from Colorado State Extension](http://www.ext.colostate.edu/pubs/foodnut/09340.html)

Comment: TY annag. Unfortunately we ate the salad and I thought about it afterward. I guess I will have to wait for the outcome!

Comment: @Patricia - I think the risk is low. I don't know the pH of your salad dressing, but the vinegar would help diminish the risk of illness.